# removing nodes in a binary tree

Tags: java, tree

This is a binary search tree using strings, I want to remove the root. [This is my binary search tree visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCXIz.png)
 If 'adam' is my root and i want to remove it, then 'beta' should be my new root.  I seem to get a NullPointerException in my deletemethod2 .

> if (nodeToDelete.parent.leftChild == nodeToDelete)

Shouldnt this method skip this if statement and move to the else if as there is nothing smaller then "adam" in my tree?
It should focus on the right side of the tree.

> else if (nodeToDelete.parent.rightChild == nodeToDelete)

```
----------

    public void remove(String word) {
            Node nodeToDelete = find(word);

            if (nodeToDelete!=null) {
                if (nodeToDelete.leftChild==null && nodeToDelete.rightChild== null) {
                    deletemethod1(nodeToDelete); // node had no children
                }
                else if(nodeToDelete.leftChild!=null && nodeToDelete.rightChild!= null){
                    deletemethod3(nodeToDelete); // both node has children
                }
                else if(nodeToDelete.leftChild!=null){
                    deletemethod2(nodeToDelete); // left child should be deleted
                }
                else if(nodeToDelete.rightChild!=null){
                    deletemethod2(nodeToDelete);// right child should be deleted
                }

            }

        }

        private void deletemethod3(Node nodeToDelete) {
            //              example
            //          50
            //              70  <-- delete
            //            59    80
            //                 65 90    
            Node minNode= minlefttraversal(nodeToDelete.rightChild); // temporarily stores the node thats being deleted
             if ((minNode.leftChild != null) || (minNode.rightChild != null)) {
                   deletemethod2(minNode); /// if minNode have right child connected to it
                  }
                  else {
                   deletemethod1(minNode);// if minNode does not have any child connected to it
                  }


            minNode.parent=nodeToDelete.parent; 
            minNode.leftChild=nodeToDelete.leftChild;
            minNode.rightChild=nodeToDelete.rightChild;
            if(nodeToDelete.parent==null){
                root= minNode;
            }
            else{

                if (nodeToDelete.parent.leftChild.equals(nodeToDelete))
                {
                    nodeToDelete.parent.leftChild = minNode;
                } 
                else if (nodeToDelete.parent.rightChild.equals(nodeToDelete))
                {
                    nodeToDelete.parent.rightChild = minNode;
                }

            }
        }   


        /* Finds minimum element in subtree rooted on leftChild */
        private Node minlefttraversal(Node node){
            if(node.leftChild==null){
                return node;
            }
            return minlefttraversal(node.leftChild);
        }

    private void deletemethod2(Node nodeToDelete) {
            //          example
            //              50
            //delete -> 20      70
            //        19       59 80

            if (nodeToDelete.parent.leftChild == nodeToDelete) {

                if (nodeToDelete.leftChild != null) {
                    nodeToDelete.parent.leftChild = nodeToDelete.leftChild;
                } else if (nodeToDelete.rightChild != null) {
                    nodeToDelete.parent.leftChild = nodeToDelete.rightChild;
                }
            } else if (nodeToDelete.parent.rightChild == nodeToDelete)

                if (nodeToDelete.leftChild != null) {
                    nodeToDelete.parent.rightChild = nodeToDelete.leftChild;
                } else if (nodeToDelete.rightChild != null) {
                    nodeToDelete.parent.rightChild = nodeToDelete.rightChild;
                }
        }

        private void deletemethod1(Node nodeToDelete){
            // check if the node that is being deleted is the left or right
            // child of the parent of the node.     

            //              example
            //                  5
            //                   \
            //  delete ->         8
            //
            if (nodeToDelete.parent == null)
            {
                nodeToDelete =null;
            }
                if (nodeToDelete.parent.leftChild==nodeToDelete) {
                    nodeToDelete.parent.leftChild = null;
                } else if (nodeToDelete.parent.rightChild.equals(nodeToDelete)) {
                    nodeToDelete.parent.rightChild = null;
                }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to remove the root, so in the condition

```
if (nodeToDelete.parent.leftChild == nodeToDelete)
```

`nodeToDelete` is the root, hence `nodeToDelete.parent` is `null` and `nodeToDelete.parent.leftChild` throws `NullPointerException`.

You must add special handling of the case when `nodeToDelete.parent == null`.